# Jackson makes extra initialization after @JsonCreator was called

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jms, deserialization

I have a simple class `A`:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
class A {

  private final String incomeField;
  private final String anotherIncomeField;
  private final String fixedValueField;

}

class B extends A {

  private B(final String incomeField, final String anotherIncomeField) {
    super(incomeField, anotherIncomeField, "someFixedValue");
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static B of(@JsonProperty("incomeField") final String incomeField, @JsonProperty("anotherIncomeField") final String anotherIncomeField) {
      return new B(incomeField, anotherIncomeField);
  }
}
```

When I push a message to ActiveMQ via `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, new B("foo", "bar"))`, the actual message in queue is the following:

```
{
   "incomeField": "foo",
   "anotherIncomeField": "bar",
   "fixedValueField": null
}
```

I handle JMS messages with `@JmsListener(destination = "my-destination)` and receive an object of type `B` with `fixedValueField` set to `null`, while I expect it to be `someFixedValue` as I set it in `private` constructor.

When I debug all this stuff, I see that `@JsonCreator` is called correctly and my object has expected values for all fields, but when Jackson finishes deserialization, I see that `fixedValueField` is `null`.
Why this can happen?

Note that all the fields are `final`

Environment:

- Java 11
- Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE
- Jackson 2.9.8
- ActiveMQ 5.15.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer why this works in such way - stackoverflow.com/a/30341178/4760059

This is possible a fix - stackoverflow.com/a/42142268/4760059